# How to dynamically create and manage multiple tables in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am maintaining a university database with 5 tables. Each table has around 2 million rows for this year. So I am planning to split the tables based on the year. I am using Spring Boot with [JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa) for my application and the database is MySQL.

For every year my application should create new tables runtime. While fetching the Entities can be able to map to both the tables.

What are all the approaches to implement?

Comment: depends on your usecase, if you are write heavy and you are locking entire table for some frequent operations sharding data across mysql table will help. if your pattern is compute heavy and want to spread the computing load into multiple physical computers then sharding data across various host will help

Comment: Why not just add index on year column? If that data isn't going to change for previous years, then you can split it offline because doing it at run time might choke resources.

Comment: all the tables are for current year. for the future years my application should create same tables with year appending

Comment: Don't create tables per year. You should read about partitioning: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html